# How to make it so that if a string is inputted, it'll return an error message?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application

I've already made it so that it can detect negative numbers and numbers over 100. That was easy enough. My issue comes in when you input a string. If you do that, it'll crash. While funny, I don't want it to do that, I want it to spit out an error message and have the user try again like I have for the other case. But I'm having a very hard time trying to figure that out.

```
Console.Write("First Grade: ");
firstGrade = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
while (firstGrade > 100 || firstGrade < 0)
{
  Console.Write("Please input a number that is greater than or equal to 0 but less than or equal to 100: ");
  firstGrade = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
}
Console.WriteLine();
```

Comment: Use [`double.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse#System_Double_TryParse_System_String_System_Double__) instead of `Convert.ToDouble`.

Comment: Learn more about [Double.TryParse Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=net-5.0)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minor change, using `double.TryParse` (as suggested by @Dmitry):

```
double firstGrade;
Console.Write("First Grade: ");
while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out firstGrade) || firstGrade > 100 || firstGrade < 0)
{
    Console.Write(@"Please input a number that is greater than or equal to 0 but less than or equal to 100: ");
}
Console.WriteLine($@"You entered: {firstGrade}");
```

Comment: If you are going to be doing this a lot, refactor your code so that the prompt, the read-line, the conversion to double and the min/max conditions if any (you can play games with `Nullable<double>` to elide a min or a max) all get passed to a `GetMeADouble` function.  That way, you can get several doubles (each with different prompts, etc) using the same method

Comment: i’ll give this a try once i’m able! let you know if it works